# How can I increase erlang process for rabbitmq?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, rabbitmq

I just changed **file descriptor** value on **rabbitmq**, now I want to update **erlang processes** too.
Below is an image that might help to answer my question
[image: erlang process value on rabbitmq]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

***Earlang process increased in a ratio with -ulimit***

I'm giving this answer from Ubuntu server perspective.

**Enter following command to open rabbitmq config. file**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/rabbitmq-server
```

**Update/Add and save it using Ctrl+x**

```
-ulimit 126666
```

**Restart your server**

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app && rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer because it is describing changing the file descriptors limit, the question specifically asks about changing the Erlang processes limit.

Comment: @SeanN are sure what you talking about, erlang process completely depending upon file descriptor/ulimit. That was mentioned on the documentation. So please know everything perfectly and then add comment. Infact this question was asked by me. Thanks.

Comment: The topic is "How can I increase erlang process for rabbitmq?" and you have a screenshot that highlights the "Erlang processes" counter. When you change the ulimit in Ubuntu you change number of File descriptors you do not change the number of Erlang processes for RabbitMQ. See "Controlling System Limits on Linux" here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

To change Erlang processes take a look at the RABBITMQ_SERVER_ERL_ARGS environment variable and @Carlo's answer.

Comment: I would recommend to follow my instruction and compare erlang process before and after. Result will be increase. So, this can't be something that can not solve the problem. :-) 
And according to your ref. https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html link, there are two types of limits, soft and hard. So, before saying anything as *not the answer* confirm you understand things correctly. 
@SeanN

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions but I can't because they don't work. Your ulimit line is incorrect because it says -ulimit and that gives an error "/etc/default/rabbitmq-server: -ulimit: not found". Anyhow, with the ulimit line corrected my results show:
No ulimit - File descriptors: 1024, Erlang processes: 1048576
With ulimit of 16000 - File descriptors: 16000, Erlang processes: 1048576
So as I have already explained twice, for the last time, ulimit affects File descriptors not Erlang processes.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)

the command line argument you are interested in is:

> +P Number|legacy
>
> ```
> Sets the maximum number of simultaneously existing processes for this system if a Number is passed as value.
> ```
>
> Valid range for Number is
>   [1024-134217727]

According to the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html), there is this environment variable `RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS` where you can add that kind of parameters.

**EDIT**
Open a shell prompt and try this:
`RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="+P 231072" rabbitmq-server`

Whenever you find a setting that satisfy you, put this `RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="+P 231072"` in a the file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`. If this file does not exist, just create it. Please note that the location for this file changes according to your installation. If you are using RabbitMQ from the tar.gz, probably you will have to create this file in `$RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/`

Comment: Yes, but its tell us its for debug purpose only
    "Standard parameters for the erl command used when invoking the RabbitMQ Server. This should be overridden for debugging purposes only."

Comment: @Sabbir Sorry, I've pasted the wrong parameter, the parameter below is the correct one. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @@Carlo Not clear to me, can you put an example config. here?